# What is the error in this programme of finding the number of times we get consecutive equal values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_count(num_list):
    count=0
    for i in num_list:
        if (i==num_list[i+1]):
            count=count+1
        else:
            pass
    return count

list=[1,1,5,100,-20,-20,6,0,0]
getCount=get_count(list)
print(getCount)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SHIVAM TYAGI/PycharmProjects/infiTQ/Day3Excercise17.py", line 12, in <module>
    getCount=get_count(list)
  File "C:/Users/SHIVAM TYAGI/PycharmProjects/infiTQ/Day3Excercise17.py", line 5, in get_count
    if (i==num_list[i+1]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `i` is not the index. It is an item in the list. `num_list[i+1]` is not the next item.

Comment: Also, even if `i` *was* the index, what would `num_list[i+1]` do in the last iteration?

Comment: but i already compare the elements in pair, like 0-1,1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5

Comment: @shivamtyagi No, you don't. As already explained, `for i in num_list` does **not** iterate over the indexes, it iterates over the elements. You  are mixing elements with indexes

Comment: The error message says all: list index out of range. Read carefully the pointed  instruction and find out: what the list is in it; what the list index is; what is that list's index range; and what must be the variable's value for the index to go out of range?

Comment: okay then can you fix this code?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are iterating over the elements of `num_list`, and trying to compare it with an element of num_list the index of which does not exist. Hence the error.

You need to iterate over the indices, till last but one element.

```
def get_count(num_list):
    count=0
    for i in range(len(num_list)-1):  # Looping from index 0 to length-1
        if (num_list[i]==num_list[i+1]):
            count=count+1
    return count

list=[1,1,5,100,-20,-20,6,0,0]
getCount=get_count(list)
print(getCount)
```